# Unable to get describe method work while iterating through a list of column names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My code is as below:

```
       Col_list=['A','B','C']
       for col in col_list:
           df.col.describe()
```

My intention above is to iterate through a list few column names which are also present in the DF and then get describe() method work. What can I try next?

Comment: `df[col].describe()`  (what you tried is equivalent to `df['col']`)

Comment: Looks like there is a case error too - `Col_list` vs. `col_list`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Col_list=['A','B','C']
for col in col_list:
    df[col].describe()
```